# Basler's Pylon SDK, on memory Image saving

Tags: c++, image

I am working on a Pylon Application where performance is crucial , saving images directly to the disk might throttle the performance, so I want to allocate a memory buffer where I can store an array of Pylon Images, and save them to disk later, what is the best approach I could take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by making an array of type (Pylon::CPylonImage) and save the captured images on it using a converter (Pylon::CImageFormatConverter) like the following code block

```
                Pylon::CImageFormatConverter::Convert(Pylon::CPylonImage[i],Pylon::CGrabResultPtr)
```