# C++(MFC) using Pylon :How to draw image which is in array

Tags: c++, image, mfc

Hello I am working on a Pylon Application, and I want to know how to draw image which is in array.

[Basler's Pylon SDK, on memory Image saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022701/baslers-pylon-sdk-on-memory-image-saving)
In this link, it shows I can save image data in array(I guess) `Pylon::CImageFormatConverter::Convert(Pylon::CPylonImage[i],Pylon::CGrabResultPtr)`
But the thing is I can not figure out how to draw that images which is in array.
I Think it would be easy problem, but I'd appreciate it if you understand because it's my first time doing this.

Comment: You can create a bitmap in Win32 by calling `CreateBitmap()` or `CreateDIBitmap()`. These can be drawn using the `BitBlt()` or `StretchBlt()` functions, or sent to an image control (check the `STM_SETIMAGE` message). Don't know about Pylon SDK, but I guess it returns an image buffer. This can be passed to the bitmap-creation functions (it must be in the proper format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick'n dirty displaying of Pylon buffers, you have a helper class available in Pylon SDK to put somewhere in buffer grabbing loop:

```
//initialization
CPylonImage img;
CPylonImageWindow wnd;

//somewhere in grabbing loop
wnd.SetImage(img);
wnd.Show();
```

If you want to utilize in your own display procedures (via either GDI or 3rd party libraries like OpenCV etc.), you can get image buffer with `GetBuffer()` method:

```
CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
camera.RetrieveResult( 5000, ptrGrabResult, TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);
const uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
```

Of course, you have to be aware of your target pixel alignment and optionally use `CImageFormatConverter` for proper output pixel format of your choice.

[CImageFormatConverter documentation](https://docs.baslerweb.com/pylonapi/cpp/class_pylon_1_1_c_image_format_converter)